# Efficient Repeated DataFrame Row Selections Based on Multiple Columns' Values

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, pandas

This is a snippet of my Data Frame in pandas

```
         SubJob   DetectorName CategoryID DefectID  Image
0             0         NECK:1         79        5   
1             0         NECK:2         79        6   
2             0         NECK:3         92        4   
3             0         NECK:4         99      123   
4             0         NECK:5         99      124   
5             1         NECK:6         79       47   
6             1         NECK:7         91      631   
7             1         NECK:8         98      646   
8             1         NECK:9         99        7   
9             2         NECK:10        79       15   
10            2         NECK:11        89     1023   
11            2         NECK:12        79     1040   
12            2         NECK:13        79     2458   
13            3         NECK:14        73     2459   
14            3         NECK:15        87     2517   
15            3         NECK:15        79     3117   
16            3         NECK:16        79     3118
```

till n which is very large

We have multiple subjobs whichare sorted inside which we have multiple categoryId which are sorted and inside categoryId we have multiple defectId which are also sorted

I have a separate nested list

[[CategoryId, DefectId, Image-Link] [CategoryId, DefectId, Image-Link] ...m times]
m is large
here category id , defect id represents integer values and image link is string

now i repeatedly pick a categoryId, DefectId from list and find a row in dataframe corresponding to that categoryId, DefectId and add image link in that row

my current code is

```
for image_info_list in final_image_info_list:
    # add path of image in Image_Link 
    frame_main.ix[(frame_main["CategoryID"].values == image_info_list[0])
                                      & 
              (frame_main["DefectID"].values == image_info_list[1]), 
               "Image_Link"] = image_info_list[2]
```

which is working perfectly but my issue is since n, m is very large it is lot of time to compute it is there any other appropriate approach

can i apply binary search here ? if yes then how

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying do?  Are you trying to get the rows in which `CategoryID`, `DefectID`, and `Image_Link` match a triplet of values?  But you also have a list of triplets?

Comment: no i am trying to find the rows where CategoryId and DefectId are present in dataframe and then add image path in image column but i am doing this task repeatdly so it is consuming lot of time i need a faster algorithm/approach for this

Comment: Have you tried setting hierarchical indexing using the CategoryID and DefectID columns? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex I believe the use of indexing should speed up the bottleneck of the comparisons across all your rows to find the matching row. I'll see if I can confirm when I get a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed *n*, if *m* is large enough, you can perform queries more efficiently by some preprocessing.

(I would start with Idea 2 below, because Idea 1 is *much* more work to implement.)

---

**Idea 1**

First, sort the dataframe by `[CategoryId, DefectId, Image-Link]`. Following that, you can find any triplet by a triple application of [a `bisect` algorithms](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html), one per column, on the column's values.

The cost of what you're doing now is *O(m n)*. The cost of my suggestion is *O(n log(n) + m log(n))*.

This will work better for some values of *m* and *n*, and worse for others. E.g., if *m = Θ(n)*, then your current algorithm is *Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) = ω(n log(n))*. YMMV.

---

**Idea 2**

Since `Image-link` is a string sequence, I'm guessing `pandas` has a harder time searching for specific values within it. You can preprocess by making a dictionary mapping each value to a list of indices within the Dataframe. In the extreme case, where each `Image-link` value has *O(1)* rows, this can reduce the time from *Θ(mn)* to *Θ(n + m)*.

**Edit**

In the extreme case the OP mentions in the comment, all `Image-link` values are unique. In this case, it is possible to build a dictionary mapping their values to indices like so:

```
dict([(k, i) for (i, k) in enumerate(df['Image-link'].values)])
```

Comment: can i set my DefectId column as index in DataFrame and then search for a DefectId will this behave like dictionary ?

Comment: @sid I have to say that this is becoming 2-3 separate questions (your original question's algorithm, how to create a mapping dictionary, how to access a row by index). SO is not a walkthrough helpdesk for the specifics of a problem. I suggest you open another question (or questions). If I see them, I'll be happy to answer. If not - I'm sure others will. In any case, ask questions with a reasonable granularity.

Comment: sure i will try your suggestions and ask other questions if necessary thank you for help